# C++ struct with template in vector

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, struct

I'm making a text adventure game in C++. This is the struct for an object in that game (something the user can pick up and put in the inventory)

```
template <int N>
struct Object
{
    static const int length = N;
    string names[N];
    string description;
};
```

Examples of objects:

```
Object<2> flower = { {"flower", "the flower"}, "A strange looking flower"};
Object<3> book = { { "the book", "book", "recipe book" }, "The world's finest cocktail recipes now all in one easy to use companion." };
```

The multiple names are synonyms for the command parser, so the user can input "pick up book" or "pick up recipe book", which in both cases picks up the object book.

Now I'd like to create a vector inventory to store all the elements in the inventory.

```
vector<Object> inventory;
```

Now, off course, this gives me a compiler error, because it expects something like this:

```
vector<Object<5>> inventory;
```

However, some objects have more names than others, is something like this possible and if so, how?

```
vector<Object<N>> inventory;
```

Comment: why do you need to keep N as a template ? , if N is different then you can use `std::vector<string> names` instead of `string names[N]`

Comment: There seems to be an obsession nowadays with writing answers in comments!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

All your different `Object<N>` classes are different types with different sizes. You can't put them in a *homogenous* container.

You would need some base class or base interface, and store pointers in the vector, relying on virtual dispatch and polymorphism when you pull the elements out. This would make your container of `Object`s a *heterogenous* container.

Alternatively, and preferably, **drop the template and store the *names* in a member container:**

```
struct Object
{
    set<string> names;
    string description;
};

vector<Object> easy;
```

<sup>PS. I don't consider `Object` to be a good name for *any* class. [CompuChip](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2920343/compuchip)'s suggestion of `InventoryItem` makes more sense.</sup>

Comment: +1 for the alternative solution, which I think is best. And for the remark about using `Object` as a class name. May I suggest something descriptive, like `InventoryItem`?

Comment: @CompuChip: I like your suggestion.

Comment: @CompuChip `object` is actually rather descriptive in games like this - the item may also be in the room, or being used as equipment, or as a hidden door etc.

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes: It may be descriptive in the game, but it is not descriptive in the code.

Comment: My point is that `InventoryItem` is overly limiting, so you're probably stuck with `Item` or `Object` to make the name fit the purpose.

Comment: `"struct for an object"` he has never said the name would be `Object` he could've changed it just for the purpose of posting it here.

Comment: @Blacktempel: That is possible, though not certain; abuse of the term "Object" is rife in game code.

Comment: Well, we don't know, and it's his game. So we can't change it without getting onto his PC. Anyway +1 for the answer.

Comment: @Blacktempel: I didn't change it. :) I merely pointed out that I think the name is poor.

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes I come from a Java/C# world where it doesn't get any more general than `object`. To me it's equivalent to "it can really be anything, I don't know what it is or what properties it even has". If `InventoryItem` is too limiting, then it's possible to come up with worse alternatives than `CarryableItem`, `InteractableItem`, `NamedWorldItem` - all of which are still better than `object` IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

A `vector` needs to know the size of the objects it contains, so obviously it cannot allow varying template instances inside (`sizeof(Object<N+X>) > sizeof(Object<N>)`).

Remove the templated array from the main `Object` struct, and replace it with a common `vector` or `list` or `string` objects instead, and your problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

Derive Object from BaseObject, and form a vector of smart pointers to BaseObject:

```
struct BaseObject
{
   virtual ~BaseObject() = default;
};

template<int N>
  struct Object : public BaseObject
{
   static const int length = N;
   string names[N];
   string description;
};

typedef shared_ptr<BaseObject> Objptr;
vector<Objptr> Inventory(1006);
```